# Miro oauth api throws error 401 Invalid authorization code

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth

[image: postman req to generate access token]

I was following this [miro doc](https://developers.miro.com/docs/getting-started-with-oauth) to prompt users to install Miro, got **stuck at step 3 while exchanging authorization code for access token** to make Miro API calls, but it keeps throwing 401 error even after using the valid credentials.
Thanks in advance for any help or insight in this matter.